# funcion que utiliza otra funcion como argumento en Python 3

Tags: python, funciones

No es una tarea, estoy aprendiendo programación con python con un vídeo tutorial de Youtube y el ejercicio una vez transcrito en código no me da los mismos resultados que en el vídeo y no se por que.

Simplemente no me hace la división y me da como resultado "None", no puedo pasar a Decoradores por este tipo de código. Agradecería su ayuda.

```py
    def revisar(func):
      def validar(x, z):
        if z == 0:
          print("No se puede dividir entre cero.")
          return
        func(x, z)
      return validar
    
    def division(a, b):
      return a / b
    
    division = revisar(division)
    
    print(division(4, 2))
```

Comment: Debes colocar `return func(x, z)` si colocas el llamado a la función abajo del `return` simplemente no se ejecuta ya que todo acaba en el `return`

Comment: Gracias, esta noche l volver analizo mejor el porque ya que necesito entenderlo para meterme con los Decoradores. Gracias

Comment: Perdona, me he confundido, al estar en celular no lo he visto bien. El `return` pertenece al `if` y está bien, lo que debes de colocar es `return func(x, z)` pues debes de retornar el resultado del llamado a la función. Lo que haces ahí es solo llamarla y no retornas nada (por defecto `None`)

Answer (score 2):

Intuyo que estás creando un *decorador* para validar los argumentos de la función `division`.

El funcionamiento buscado sería:

```py
>>> division(4, 2)
2
>>> division(4, 0)
No se puede dividir entre cero.
```

El *decorador* se puede usar como has puesto en el código, pero resulta más claro y *pythónico* usarlo con el prefijo `@`:

```py
@revisar
def division(a, b):
    return a / b
```

Veamos cómo definir el decorador `revisar`:

Como argumento entra una función de dos argumentos para validar que no sea 0 el segundo argumento. Para ello creamos una función interna que valide los argumentos antes de invocar a la función original:

```py
def revisar(f):

    def wrapper(x, y):
        if y == 0:
            print("No se puede dividir entre cero.")
            return None
        return f(x, y)

    return wrapper
```

`revisar(division)` nos devuelve una función *wrapper* de modo que `wrapper(x, y)` chequea que `y != 0` antes de ejecutar `division(x, y)`.

Sólo existe un problema que suele pasar desapercibido: la función `division` ha perdido su nombre e, incluso, sus *docstrings* (si las tuviera):

```py
>>> division.__name__
'wrapper'
```

Sin entrar en detalles, la solución pasa por usar [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```py
from functools import wraps

def revisar(f):

    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(x, y):
        if y == 0:
            print("No se puede dividir entre cero.")
            return None
        return f(x, y)

    return wrapper

@revisar
def division(a, b):
    """División de dos números reales"""
    return a / b
```

```py
>>> division.__name__
'division'

>>> division.__doc__
'División de dos números reales'
```

Comment: Tu explicación va mas allá de por donde voy en el vídeo curso y me cuesta seguirte. Aun así gracias.

Comment: Siempre hay que tener presente que estas respuestas deben servir a otras gentes que se pasen por aquí el futuro. Seguramente, tu pregunta esté ya respondida con la primera parte de mi respuesta. Siempre puedes pedir que te aclaremos lo que no veas claro.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de la función validar, en caso de que no se cumpla la condición z == 0, debes retornar la función **func()**

```
def validar(x, z):
    if z == 0:
      print("No se puede dividir entre cero.")
      return
    # Aquí corriges
    return func(x, z) # antes no había return
```